# Highstock showing dates where there's no Data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highstock, but not as it should be used, i'm more using it as a highcharts plus the navigator functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/ygyx5r9r/

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                'type': 'datetime',
                        'title': {
                            'text': 'Time'
                        }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,6),0.7549],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,7),0.7562],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,9),0.7574],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,10),0.7543],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,11),0.7510],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,12),0.7498],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,13),0.7477],
    [Date.UTC(2013,5,14),0.7492]]

            }, ]
        });
    });
```

And as exposed in my jsfiddle you can see that theres no data between the 6 and 9 Jun, and that's not shown in my highstock chart are they anyway to keep the dates where theres no data as highcharts does ? i'm using it for diagnostic but i like the navigator i find it very convenient .

Any help would be great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highstock's xAxis is by default [`ordinal`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) - this means that empty spaces will not be shown. To fix your problem you could set `ordinal` to `false` for `xAxis`.

```
...
xAxis: {
  ordinal: false,
...
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mxtv0ztc/